# Independence of random variables iff equality of product distribution to product of distributions.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathcal{\mathbb{P}}\right)$
, a measurable space $\left(S,\mathcal{S}\right)$
  and a measurable function $X:\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F}\right)\to\left(S,\mathcal{S}\right)$
  we define the distribution of $X$
  to be $\mu_{X}\left(E\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X^{-1}\left[E\right]\right)$
  , $\forall\: E\in\mathcal{S}$

Now Let $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}\right)$
  be a probability space and let $X,Y
 :\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F}\right)\to\left(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}\right)$
  be two random variables ($\mathcal{B}$
  being the Borel $\sigma$
 -algebra on $\mathbb{R}$)
 . I want to show that $X,Y$
  are independent iff $$\left(\mu_{X}\times\mu_{Y}\right)\left(E\right)=\mu_{\left(X,Y\right)}\left(E\right)$$
  for all $E\in\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^{2}\right)$
 . The non-trivial direction is showing that independence implies the equality of the measures but the strategy is generally clear to me. The set $\left\{ A\times B\,|\, A,B\in\mathcal{B}\right\}$ 
  is a $\pi$
 -system that generates $\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^{2}\right)$
  (since the the product of Borel $\sigma$
 -algebras is the Borel $\sigma$-
 algebra on the product in our case). All that remains is to show that $$\mathcal{L}:=\left\{ E\in\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^{2}\right)\,|\,\left(\mu_{X}\times\mu_{Y}\right)\left(E\right)=\mu_{\left(X,Y\right)}\left(E\right)\right\}$$
 Is a $\lambda$
 -system and the proof will be complete from the $\pi-\lambda$
  Theorem (as $\mathcal{P}\subseteq\mathcal{L}$
  almost immediately). I'm having difficulty showing that $\mathcal{L}$ is closed under increasing unions.
Let $A_{1},A_{2},...\in\mathcal{L}$
  be a sequence such that $A_{n-1}\subseteq A_{n}$
 . I can turn the increasing union into a disjoint union by defining $B_{n}=A_{n}\backslash\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_{i}$
  and then I would like to write the following:$$\mu_{\left(X,Y\right)}\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\right)=\mu_{\left(X,Y\right)}\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}\right)\overbrace{=}^{\mbox{Disjoint}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_{\left(X,Y\right)}\left(B_{n}\right)$$
 $$\overbrace{=}^{??}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\mu_{X}\times\mu_{Y}\right)\left(B_{n}\right)\overbrace{=}^{\mbox{Disjoint}}\left(\mu_{X}\times\mu_{Y}\right)\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}\right)=\left(\mu_{X}\times\mu_{Y}\right)\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\right)$$
 My problem is with the marked equality, if I knew that $B_{n}$
  was in $\mathcal{L}$
  then I'd have that and for that it would suffice to know that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_{i}$ is in $\mathcal{L}$ as I proved closure to relative complement.

I'd appreciate help finalizing this detail.

Comment: What is your definition of independence?

Comment: I looked it up and there are indeed a bunch of equivalent ways to define independence. I think that for two R.Vs the most common one is that $\mathbb{P}\left[X^{-1}\left[A\right]\cap Y^{-1}\left[B\right]\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[X^{-1}\left[A\right]\right]\mathbb{P}\left[X^{-1}\left[B\right]\right]$ for all $A,B\in\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^{2}\right)$

Comment: It is worth knowing that the collection of measurable sets where two probability measures agree is always an $\lambda$-system (not just for product measures).

Comment: @ByronSchmuland it's nice that you mentioned that, I assumed that much is true and I had a question on the matter. In my proof in order to show closure to relative complement I used the fact that all the measures in questions are finite and thus the measure of the relative complement is easily expressed as the difference in measures. But suppose that the measures were not finite, how do you you show closure for relative complement without risking expressions of the form $\infty-\infty$ ?

Comment: @Serpahimz It's not true for infinite measures.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Oh, well that certainly answers that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\mu_{(X,Y)}(B_n)=\mu_{(X,Y)}(A_n)-\mu_{(X,Y)}(A_{n-1})$ for each $n$. Then we use the fact that $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$ belong to $\mathcal L$.

Actually, there is no need to go back to disjoint unions, unless we don't have already proved that for a measure $\nu$ and a non-decreasing sequence $(S_n)$, with $S:=\bigcup_n S_n$, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}\nu(S_n)=\nu(S)$.

Comment: How silly of me to not notice that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}A_{i}=A_{n-1}$... And indeed I suppose I could also have used continuity of measures which is even easier.